# Adding TR inside td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tr

I am trying to add `tr` inside `td` . I want to achieve like this.
http://jsfiddle.net/yp4cLds9/.

But I wanted to add `tr` when button is clicked.

my java script logic

```
$('#tbUsers2 tr').each(function (e) {
    var trow = $(this);


    if (count== 0) {
        trow.append('<td class="calculated-value"><input type="text" value="Chem Volume' + iter + '" disabled/></td>');

        count++;
    }   
    else {
        trow.append("<tr><td></td><td><input type='text' value='Chem Volume'></td></tr>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Question is unclear. please read:- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well a TR is not a child of a TD so not possible. You can insert the row after the row.

Comment: If it is a must then you will need to add a new `table > tr > td` inside the `td`

Comment: please check the jsfiddle link which i shared above

Comment: @AlivetoDie check my jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

It is always not suggested to add 'tr' within 'td'. But still if you have to do it, then here you can do it with JavaScript:

```
function addTr(){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = '<td>Hello</td>';

    document.getElementById("anyTDid").append(tr);
}
```

Comment: _"It is always not suggested to add 'tr' within 'td'"_ - It's not _allowed_ as this would generate invalid markup.

Comment: so how can i achieve this layout of table http://jsfiddle.net/yp4cLds9/